# starting new activity from asyncTask within AlertDialog crash

Tags: android, android-asynctask

As the title of this question says, I have code such as below:

```
protected void PayMessageBox(final String Type) {

    AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setMessage("are you sure?")
            .setPositiveButton("yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        // do something when the button is clicked
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            new AsyncGetAccountInfo().execute(Type);
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("no",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        // do something when the button is clicked
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        }
                    }).show();


}
```

within the AsyncGetAccountInfo(), I have the following code:

```
protected class AsyncGetAccountInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // private Boolean Havemoney = true;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            String allPlace = null;
            RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
            try {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                        "MyData", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String E_MSISDN = sharedPreferences.getString("MSISDN",
                        "N/A");

                EncryptDecryptWithDESUsingPassPhrase security = new EncryptDecryptWithDESUsingPassPhrase();

                // E_MSISDN=security.encrypt(E_MSISDN);
                String E_ACTIVATIONCODE = sharedPreferences.getString(
                        "ACTIVATIONCODE", "N/A");
                Long ReqId = sharedPreferences.getLong("REQID", -1);

                String Key = ReqId + E_ACTIVATIONCODE;
                security.setKey(Key);
                String E_IMEI = security.encrypt(IMEI);
                String E_TYPE = security.encrypt(params[0]);

                JSONObject jsonObj = api.ReduceCharge(E_IMEI,E_MSISDN,
                        E_TYPE);
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                allPlace = parser.parseReduceCharge(jsonObj);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                // Log.d("AsyncUserDetails", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return allPlace;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            // Log.d("AsyncUserDetails", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        // return Havemoney;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (result != null) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                    "MyData", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Long ReqId = sharedPreferences.getLong("REQID", -1);

            EncryptDecryptWithDESUsingPassPhrase security = new EncryptDecryptWithDESUsingPassPhrase();
            String E_ACTIVATIONCODE = sharedPreferences.getString(
                    "ACTIVATIONCODE", "N/A");
            ReqId = sharedPreferences.getLong("REQID", -1);
            String Key = ReqId + E_ACTIVATIONCODE;
            security.setKey(Key);

            if (security.decrypt(result).equals("1")) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putLong("REQID", ++ReqId);
                editor.commit();
                // new AsyncSaveMobileAndActivationCode().execute(result);
                dialog.dismiss();
                new AsyncPersonIsPaid().execute();
                if(true)
                    {
                    //new AsyncUserPackagepaid().execute();

                    }

                if (SingleVideos.size() > 0) {
                    // progressBar.startAnimation(set);
                    DownloadVideo(SingleVideos.get(0).VIDEOURL);
                }

            } else if (security.decrypt(result).equals("-2")) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putLong("REQID", ++ReqId);
                editor.commit();

                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "low balance",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putLong("REQID", ++ReqId);
                editor.commit();

                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "try again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "db down, try later",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // LL_Register_Button.setClickable(true);
        }

    }

}
```

After the code comes to the below point:

```
if (SingleVideos.size() > 0) {
                    // progressBar.startAnimation(set);
                    DownloadVideo(SingleVideos.get(0).VIDEOURL);
                }
```

The DownloadVideo is called which has the below code:

```
private void DownloadVideo(final String VIDEO_URL) {

    try {

        if (VIDEO_URL != null && VIDEO_URL.length() > 0) {

            File file = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getAbsolutePath());

            VideoPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/" + Uri.parse(VIDEO_URL).getLastPathSegment();

            getfile(file);

            int countVideo = 0;
            for (File video_name : fileList) {
                if (video_name.getName().equals(
                        Uri.parse(VIDEO_URL).getLastPathSegment()))
                    countVideo++;
            }
            if (countVideo > 0) {

                PersonInfo.mMediaPlayer.pause();
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri myUri = Uri.parse(VideoPath);
                String VideoExtention = VideoPath.substring(0,
                        VideoPath.lastIndexOf('.'));
                String extentions = "video/"
                        + VideoPath.substring(VideoExtention.length() + 1);
                intent.setDataAndType(myUri, extentions);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {

                if (IsOnline) {// stream video
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                            PlayVideoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("VIDEOPATH", VIDEO_URL);
                    intent.putExtra("ISONLINE", true);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                if (IsOnline == false) {// donwload video
                    float VideoSize = 0f;
                    String last2 = (TV_VideoSize.getText() == null
                            || TV_VideoSize.length() < 2 ? "0"
                            : ((String) TV_VideoSize.getText())
                                    .substring(TV_VideoSize.getText()
                                            .length() - 2));

                    last2 = last2.trim();
                    String NewString = ((String) TV_VideoSize.getText())
                            .replaceAll(last2, "");
                    if (last2.equals("KB")) {
                        VideoSize = Float.valueOf(NewString) * 1024f;
                    } else if (last2.equals("MB")) {
                        VideoSize = Float.valueOf(NewString) * 1024f * 1024f;
                    } else if (last2.equals("GB")) {
                        VideoSize = Float.valueOf(NewString) * 1024f * 1024f * 1024f;
                    } else {
                        VideoSize = Float.valueOf(NewString);// byte
                    }

                    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
                            .getAbsolutePath());

                    float bytesAvailable = (float) stat.getBlockSize()
                            * (float) stat.getAvailableBlocks();

                    if (bytesAvailable > VideoSize) {
                        myTask = new MyTask();
                        myTask.execute(VIDEO_URL);
                        // myTask.cancel(true);
                    } else {

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(context, "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code enters within this part of above code:

```
if (IsOnline) {// stream video
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                            PlayVideoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("VIDEOPATH", VIDEO_URL);
                    intent.putExtra("ISONLINE", true);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

The issue is that startActivity(intent) in above code, which is basically VideoView's activity, even the onCreate of it is called and when it wants to execute the videoView.start() method, it crashs.

What is going wrong?

Comment: can you post `PlayVideoActivity.class`

Comment: Can you post the logcat of the crash?

Comment: where is `context` coming from? EDIT NVM I see